# Change color label TablePagination Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have that table with that label for pagination.

[image]

(1-10 de 15)

And I use the TablePagination from Material UI.

```
import TablePagination from '@mui/material/TablePagination';
```

I would like to know how I change this label's color.

Answer (score 1):

you can open the chrome dev tools and inspect/check the CSS rule used for particular component then use that rule name in SX props and overwrite it with your own css properties. You can also check the API page for that component for all CSS rules used in the component.

for your case check following code,

```
<TablePagination
...
  sx={{
    ".MuiTablePagination-displayedRows": {
      color: "red",
    },
    ".MuiTablePagination-selectLabel": {
      color: "green",
    },
  }}
/>
```

[image: Edit TablePagination Material Demo (forked)]